# How to use clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to javascript and Meteor and trying to clearTimeout on a function of a function.

The console states cannot find property of. I did not write the code so I am at a loss of how to stop the timer.

Any suggestions are appreciated!
Code:

```
function startTimer(){
  start = new Date().getTime();
  time = 0;
  elapsed = '0.0';

    function instance(){
       time += 100;
       console.log('instance started');
       elapsed = Math.floor(time / 100) / 10;
       if(Math.round(elapsed) == elapsed) { elapsed += '.0'; }
          document.title = elapsed;

       var diff = (new Date().getTime() - start) - time;
       window.setTimeout(instance, (100 - diff));
    };
  window.setTimeout(instance, 100);
};

 function stopTimer() {
   clearTimeout();
 };
```

Comment: You have to pass a parameter to `clearTimeout`. And what does this have to do with Meteor?

Comment: ok, can you give me an example of passing a parameter?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Stack Overflow is not the right place to come for basic questions and examples. Some extremely good resources such as the MDN exist, I suggest you search over there.

Comment: @Kyll ok the parameter question is a bit weird, but I guess it's just an understanding problem.. remember yourself in the early days

Comment: Thats unfortunate that stack overflow is not the place for some basic questions. I googled what I needed to enter to stop the timer and clearTimout(); was the only answer. I also set the .setTimeout() to a variable and I keep getting console messages that instance is not defined. Is not the function instance a globally accessible? So I apologize if I offended you with my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// define myTimeout somewhere globally
var myTimeout;

function instance() {
    ...
    myTimeout = setTimeout(instance, 100);
}

function stop() {
     clearTimeout(myTimeout);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @webdeb It wasnt a drop in but it lead me in the right direction and thank you for understanding. I will spend the next days going over terminology and making sure I improve my understanding.