# How does clearTimeout work, for clearing timeouts when the previous one is still running?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a play & pause button for my video. This video will disappear when the timeout is done, because it will toggle the .active class off, which will return it back to 0 opacity. I've tied this to a `onmousemove`For this I'm using the clearTimeout.

I can't get it to work. The play button will flicker, because the class keeps getting added.

This is my function

```
const togglePlay = (...args) => playButton.classList.toggle(...args);
var timer = null;
     vid.onmousemove = function(){

        if (timer!= null){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        else {
            togglePlay("active");
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                togglePlay("active");
                stopTime();
            }, 2000);
        }
     }
```

I've already read multiple other post with this same problem. I tried implementing this: [How to use clearTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613778/how-to-use-cleartimeout)

And I got the timer=null from another post.

I've also attemped it in anotherway, by disabling the togglePlay instead. This did work for what I wanted achieve, but by testing the console log, it was still firing a lot in the background.

I did that like this

```
     var timer = null;
     vid.onmousemove = function(){


        if (timer != null){
            console.log("TimedOut"); 
        }
        else {
            //right here is the mistake, this is not a timer
            timer = togglePlay("active");
            setTimeout(() => {
                togglePlay("active");
                timer = null;
                console.log("setTimeout");
            }, 2000);  
        }
     }
```

This code kind of defeats the purpose of the clearTimeout though. So my question really. What am I doing wrong with the setTimeout?

Comment: Why are you using onmousemove to clear the timeout? I'm confused as to why you actually need a timeout here. Is it to pause playback after 2 seconds? Or to pause playback on mouse move? Sorry I am just a little confused as to what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: It's like when you're watching a YouTube video, or even Netflix. When you move your mouse over the window, the pause button will appear. But when you stop moving your mouse, it will fadeout after a set amount of time. 

This is what I'm trying to achieve. Where it will toggle a class for just 2 seconds.

Comment: `mousemove` fires continuously as long as the mouse is moving; you probably want `mouseenter` instead.  (Or if you need to capture movement within the element, [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the event.)

Comment: I know it's moving indeed, but what I want to know is how to prevent it from firing at all. I did read the debounce, but I found it hard to wrap my head around it, so I'm trying to build it by myself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first shown function should work fine if you remove the call to `togglePlay` right before you call `setTimeout`:

```js
const vid = document.querySelector('#foo');

const togglePlay = (...args) => vid.classList.toggle(...args);

var timer = null;
vid.onmousemove = function(){
  if (timer){ clearTimeout(timer); }
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
      togglePlay("active");
      // stopTime();
  }, 500);

}
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #c00;
}

#foo.active {
  background: #090;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

This code *debounces* the action with each mousemove. If you want to have *throttling*, do it this way:

```js
const vid = document.querySelector('#foo');

const togglePlay = (...args) => vid.classList.toggle(...args);

var timer = null;
vid.onmousemove = function(){
  if (!timer){
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      togglePlay("active");
      timer = null;
      // stopTime();
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #c00;
}

#foo.active {
  background: #090;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Accepted your answer as best, because it also makes me understand the timeout function!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use the timer to implement a cool-down period during which no class change should be allowed.

In that case do nothing when the timer variable is non-null, but also set the variable back to `null` when the delay has expired:

```
var timer = null;
vid.onmousemove = function(){
    if (timer !== null) return; // Don't do anything if cool-down period is not yet over
    togglePlay("active");
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        togglePlay("active");
        timer = null; // Cool-down is over now.
        stopTime();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: This is working!

So instead of my console log, you did return?

Comment: Well, both of your code versions have something different. The first one clears the timer when it shouldn't, and the second one does not assign the correct value to `timer`. The first one does not set the timer back to `null` either.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your problem, you probably need to store timerid on an array instead on a simple variable. Use:

```
var timers = [];
```

and

```
timers.push(setTimeout(...));
```

and for clear timeouts use:

```
if (timers.length > 0)
```

and then:

```
for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; ++i) {
    clearTimeout(timers[i]);
}
timers = [];
```

However I personally do not like to use clear timeout option. Instead I usually use timer instance both stored on a local variable and passed to timeout as a parameter. Then I check inside the timer if this is the lastone called or if it is the one that I'm interested in.

```
var localctr = 0;
setTimeout(function(thisctr) {
    if (thisctr == localctr) {
        // ... this is the latest
    }
}, 2000, ++localctr);
```

On this approach if you increase localctr on other event will effectively disable the timer.